# Delete sub-domain cookie, which was set by a sub-domain

Tags: javascript

I create a cookie within a subdomain (new.domain.com), however I need to clear this cookie on another sub-domain, as this is simply a login token which needs to be accessible across multiple sub-domains.

```
document.cookie = 'token=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.com';
```

However the above code simply won't delete this cookie, which is being ran from lets say (old.domain.com).

Comment: How is this cookie generated? If it is generated with the `HttpOnly` flag then it is not possible to delete it through client side code. [More](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)

Comment: @leopal Ah, this could be the issue! It is created using Laravel, which appears to have this on by default!

Comment: @leopal Yes this was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cookie cannot be deleted with client side code when `HttpOnly` flag is used.

Quoting from [docs](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#What_is_HttpOnly.3F):

> Using the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of client side script accessing the protected cookie (if the browser supports it).

So in order to be able to remove it, the aforementioned flag should not be set when the cookie is created.